# Error using Aspose.Email to open an embedded PDF attachment, then load into Datalogics

Tags: pdf, aspose

I am using using the Aspose.Email to get attachments out of an Outlook email like this:

```
var mailMessage = Aspose.Email.Mail.MailMessage.Load(stream);
var attachments = Aspose.Email.Outlook.MapiMessage.FromMailMessage(mailMessage).Attachments;
var pdfAttachment = attachments.ToList()[attachmentIndexDesired];
```

Then, I am loading the attachment into DataLogics like this:

```
var pdfStream = new MemoryStream(pdfAttachment.BinaryData);
var pdfDocument = new Datalogics.PDFL.Document(pdfStream);
```

Here I get the following exception:

> PDF Library Error: File does not begin with '%PDF-'. Error number: 537001985

I cannot find anything on this error anywhere.

Note that the initial stream object above is a *.msg Outlook file and originates from a sharepoint SPFile.  Also note that if the stream object SPFile is itself a PDF file (as opposed to an attachment to a *.msg file) I can load it into DataLogics just fine.

I know the error is being thrown by the DataLogics library, but is there something about how I am getting the attachment that could be changed/improved that would prevent this error from occurring?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So just a few minutes ago I was trying to grab the BinaryData from the attachment and convert it to a string that I could read so I could visually inspect its contents.  So I did this.

```
(new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(curAttachment.BinaryData))).ReadToEnd()
```

When I did that, it printed this error:

```
"Evaluation copy of Aspose.Email limits to extract only 3 attachments in the messages. Please contact sales@aspose.com to purchase a valid license."
```

Kind of strange as I am using my production license, but either way I went ahead and deleted some attachments from the parent *.msg file (it previously had 4) and tried to load it again.  Then... poof... it started working.

Seems like it should throw an exception or something instead as that would have made this issue a lot easier to track down.

Comment: If it's a valid license for Aspose.Email product, then it must not corrupt the PDF attachment (3 or more). Please report in Aspose forums with sample code and MSG file.